# Rosetta Stone on Windows 10 can't recognize speech but it worked fine in Windows 8

Tags: rosetta-stone

I used Rosetta Stone on Windows 8, but now I use windows 10 and it is not working.

I first installed the latest version and it couldn't recognize my voice, so I uninstalled it and installed the third version, and I faced the same problem.

My microphone works fine and I tried it on other programs and it works perfectly.

Comment: all i want to say is that rosetta stone can't recognize my voice

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if all **Rosetta Stone Speech Recognition Packages** are installed.

There are 2 packages. First one is the engine and other one is the model. If it still doesn't work be sure your **microphone volume is set somewhere between 75 and 90 percent**. You can change it from the **Control Panel.**

If it still doesn't work use a **USB Headset.** Rosetta Stone officially requires the use of a USB headset *note that it also works with built-in laptop microphones but sometimes it causes problems.*

The last solution is to **disable all other programs that uses your microphone when you're working with Rosetta Stone Speech Recognition.**

Let me know whether it worked or not please.

Here is the [source](https://ithelp.brown.edu/kb/articles/troubleshoot-microphone-errors-in-rosetta-stone) that I used to create this answer.

Comment: where can i see if the packages are installed?

Comment: Install packages manually:

https://download.trstone.com/productsupport/RS_Speech_Models_and_Engine_Installers.zip

Comment: it can't be downloaded :( can you try it and see if the problem is from my computer or the link

Comment: Does this work? It doesn’t seem to be loading maybe my internet is slow https://download.trstone.com/productdownload/RS_Speech_Models_and_Engine_Installers.zip

Comment: isn't it the same link? anyways i tried it and it didn't work

Comment: @Zanyar Plug in your microphone headset. Follow the Microphone Selection prompts. If your microphone is not listed, click Refresh List. When you’ve selected your microphone, continue to Microphone Setup. this is the only way I’ve found: [Rosetta PDF](http://resources.rosettastone.com/CDN/de/pdfs/RSV3_QS_CD_English_US.pdf)

Comment: i tried that also but it didn't help, anyway thank you so much for your effort